# Cannot display React UI, Blank white page being displayed only

Tags: reactjs, vite, npx, ethers.js, hardhat

Im working on an NFT minting frontend with react, but it's giving me issues (as always). For some reason, it only displays a blank white page, which I'm struggling to understand. This is my main.jsx

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import './index.css'
import App from './App'

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

and this is my App.jsx [it's A LOT more than just this, I'm just trying to get it to display any damn text :( ]

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import logo from './logo.svg'
import './App.css'
import Install from './components/Install'

function App() {

const [count, setCount] = useState(0)

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>Hello Vite + React!</p>
      </header>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Any feedback would be appreciated

Comment: Is not only white... Open the browser console and paste what is throw in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try to remove unused packages and components. For this case `Install` component.

Comment: that actually did the trick, thanks a bunch, but Im still not sure why. Like, I need the file that Im importing, and even when I use it, I still get some issues